# Make imacros work with about:config of Firefox

Tags: firefox, imacros

Is there any way to change the values in about:config using the imacros.

i tried every possible thing which came to my mind but could not get any solution.

i dont know much of javascript so cant figure out a way but i know there is a way out through java script.

Comment: about:config is not a web site. It's settings inside FireFox.

Comment: so wont imacros change any settings of firefox in about:config??

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Javascript interface for Imacros for Firefox.
save in macro.js and run the following code:

```
"use strict";
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=about:config\n WAIT SECONDS=1");
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

prefs.setBoolPref("pdfjs.disabled", true);
prefs.setIntPref("browser.download.folderList", 2);
prefs.setCharPref("browser.download.dir", "C:\\");
```